# ngram matching gives same score to less relevant documents

Tags: elasticsearch, match, n-gram, relevance

I am searching for Bob Smith in my elasticsearch index. The results Bob Smith and Bobbi Smith both come back in the response with the same score. I want Bob Smith to have a higher score so that it appears first in my result set. Why are the scores the equivalent?

Here is my query

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Bob Smith",
            "fields": [
                "text_field"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Below are my index's settings. I am using the ngram token filter described here: https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch

```
{
    "contacts_5test": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "text_field": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "term_vector": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_filter_analyzer"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "contacts_5test",
                "creation_date": "1588987227997",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "ngram_filter": {
                            "type": "nGram",
                            "min_gram": "4",
                            "max_gram": "4"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "ngram_filter_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "ngram_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "HqOXu9bNRwCHSeK39WWlxw",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7060199"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results from my query...

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "contacts_5test",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.69795835,
    "_source": {
      "text_field": "Bob Smith"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "contacts_5test",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.69795835,
    "_source": {
      "text_field": "Bobbi Smith"
    }
  }
]
```

If I instead search for Bobbi Smith, elastic returns both documents, but with a higher score for Bobbi Smith. This makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and reason for this is due to the use of your `ngram_filter`, which doesn't create any token for `bob` as the minimum length of the token should be `4` while standard tokenizer created `bob` token but then it gets filtered out in your `ngram_filter` where you mentioned `min_gram` as `4`.

Even I tried with less `min_gram` length to `3`,  which would create the tokens but the issue is that both `bob` and `bobbie` will have same `bob` tokens, hence score for both of them will be same.

While when you search for `Bobbi Smith`, then `bobbi` ie exact token will be present only in one document, hence you get the higher score.

Note:- Please use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) and [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to inspect the tokens generated and how these are matched, this would help you to understand the issue and my explanation in details and my

Comment: Is there a way to tune the ngram filter so that we can get Bobbi to show up in the results if on a search for “Bob”?

Comment: you mean `Bobbi` to not come in search result or come with less score?